# Connecting Arduino101 to a Java Application in PC via BLE

Tags: java, arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My arduino101 reads values from analog pin A0, and I want to access it in a Java program in PC via its built-in Bluetooth. I am new in Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) and I've tried to find answers everywhere but seems like nobody have tried it yet. My laptop can see and connect to the arduino101. I just want to know how to connect to it in a java program instead of using the serial monitor.

Answer (score 1):

The Bluetooth connection is actually a serial connection (UART) and it is called SPP (Serial Port Profile). This makes the communication between host and remote device easier so that user can access via a simple UART connection over either a terminal or a MCU. If you scan/find and connect arduino101 from your laptop then you can use serial communication to send and read data from Bluetooth.